# Rails i18n shows the variables but not the value (translation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm trying to implement the i18n for multi languages in my rails project. Partly it works, eg. in navigation which is part of the application.html.erb and implemented like this:

```
<%=t :about %>
```

The application.rb is structured like follow:

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Regional
  class Application < Rails::Application
    I18n.available_locales = [:en, :de]
    I18n.default_locale = :en
  end
end
```

The application_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    {locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
end
```

The main body of the landing page is in another file index.html.erb and the i18n is used like this:

```
<div class="section-title text-center center">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h2><%=t :regionalTitle %></h2>
      <hr>
      <p><%=t :regionalSubTitle %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But instead of getting the right translation, the website only shows the variables but not the values:
[i18n doesnt show value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP4J4.png)

**Info Update:** It even doesn't show the english text.

I tried to use the i18n controller code also for the landing page but didn't help

```
    private 
    def set_locale
        I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
      end

      def default_url_options(options = {})
        {locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
      end
```

UPDATE:
Here are the log files. First when I simply reload the file, second when I choose english.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-10 18:27:16 +0200
Processing by LandingpageController#index as HTML
  Rendering landingpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered landingpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application (19.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 89ms (Views: 85.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-10 18:27:19 +0200
Processing by LandingpageController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  Rendering landingpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered landingpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application (19.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 101.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/de" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-10 18:33:43 +0200
Processing by LandingpageController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"de"}
  Rendering landingpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered landingpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application (25.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 95ms (Views: 92.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

UPDATE: 
Path and hierarchy of the folders.[Hierarchy and file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oMv6.png)

Comment: Can you verify that the path and filename of the view match the hierarchy in the translation yaml file

Comment: @YoavEpstein see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oMv6.png

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `params[:locale]` is `nil`, so it is going to `I18n.default_locale` where you have `:en` as your `default_locale`. So you are seeing the *normal text(`:en`) instead of your translated text*(`:de`).

You can debug it by sending an explicit value like below to make sure that `params[:locale]` is `nil`.

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = 'de' || I18n.default_locale
end
```

Comment: It even doesn't show the original english text, only the variables. Your solution is implemented but doesn't change the result. Also tried to copy the landingpage.html.erb code into the application.html.erb but also then (where the navigation and footer works with translation) also there it doesn't display it correct.

Comment: @korbi Can you update the question with the related server log?

Comment: for sure, see above

Comment: @korbi Ok. So while choosing `de` doesn't change the text to translated text?

Comment: No, checked the file everything exactly 100% the same like in english. but also the english doesn't work. only in the navbar and footer which are in the application.html.erb but everything in the index.html.erb doesn't work